# Aperiodic states interpretation problem

Tags: markov-chains

After reading about periodicity of states in Markov chains I have problems understanding intuitively the *aperiodic* states.

Following the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Periodicity) if the return to one state can be done in $3n$ and $5n$ steps ($n\in \mathbb{N}$), then the period will be g.c.d{3,5} = 1. So the chain will be aperiodic. I found it counterintuitive as the return can only be done in $3n$ or $5n$ steps. That seems to me a periodic (informally speaking) behavior.

[This](http://courses.washington.edu/inde411/MarkovChains(part3).pdf) source uses the Wikipedia definition of period but a more  intuitive (to me) definition of aperiodic state. My problem here is that I cannot fit my example into that definition.

Can someone help me to understand this? Please, consider that I'm not a mathematician

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1393012/265466) for a succinct description of Markov chain state periodicity.

Comment: @amd Thanks, very good source! I still do not get how the both definitions of aperiodic are equivalent.